# Comparison between $\sup W$ and $\sup \overline{W}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

It is well-known that $\sup S= \sup \overline{S}$ for any nonempty $S\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Now, let $W$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{C}^d$ and $\overline{W}$ be the closure of $W$ with respect to the topology of $\mathbb{C}^d$.

> Is
>   $$\sup\{\|\lambda\|_2,\;\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_d) \in W\}=\sup\{\|\lambda\|_2,\;\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_d) \in \overline{W}\}\;?,$$
>   where
>   $$\|\lambda\|_2:=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^d|\lambda_k|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$

Clearly
$$\sup\{\|\lambda\|_2,\;\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_d) \in W\}\leq\sup\{\|\lambda\|_2,\;\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_d) \in \overline{W}\}\;.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\mathbb{C}^d\to\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda\mapsto\|\lambda\|_2$ is continuous.

If $W$ is unbounded, then $\sup\{\|\lambda\|_2:\lambda\in W\}=\infty$ and the same is obviously true for $\overline{W}\supseteq W$.

Suppose $W$ is bounded and set $s=\sup\{\|\lambda\|_2:\lambda\in W\}$. Let $\lambda\in\overline{W}$; then there exists a sequence $(\lambda_n)$ in $W$ converging to $\lambda$; then, by continuity, $\|\lambda\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|\lambda_n\|$; since  $\|\lambda_n\|\le s$ for all $n$, also $\|\lambda\|\le s$.

Hence $\sup\{\|\lambda\|_2:\lambda\in \overline{W}\}\le s$. The converse inequality follows from $W\subseteq\overline{W}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where exactely you have used the fact that $W$ is a nonempty subset? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Schüler If $W=\emptyset$, then $\sup\{\|\lambda\|:\lambda\in W\}=-\infty$ and the same for $\overline{W}=\emptyset$. There's actually no need to assume $W\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: I think that your proof works in normed spaces not only $C^d$. Do you agree with me? Thanks

Comment: @Schüler Certainly so! The norm function is (uniformly) continuous with respect to the topology defined by the norm itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are equal. Suppose otherwise. That is, suppose that$$\sup\left\{\lVert\lambda\rVert_2\,\middle|\,\lambda\in W\right\}<\sup\left\{\lVert\lambda\rVert_2\,\middle|\,\lambda\in\overline W\right\}.$$Let$$s=\sup\left\{\lVert\lambda\rVert_2\,\middle|\,\lambda\in W\right\}\text{ and let }S=\sup\left\{\lVert\lambda\rVert_2\,\middle|\,\lambda\in\overline W\right\}.$$You are assuming that $s<S$. There is some $\lambda\in\overline W$ such that$$S-\lVert\lambda\rVert_2<\frac{S-s}2\tag1$$and there is some $\lambda^\ast\in W$ such that $\lVert\lambda-\lambda^\ast\rVert_2<\frac{S-2}2$, which implies that$$\lVert\lambda\rVert_2-\lVert\lambda^\ast\rVert_2<\frac{S-s}2.\tag2$$But then it follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $S-\lVert\lambda^\ast\rVert_2<S-s$ and therefore $\lVert\lambda^\ast\rVert_2>s$, which is impossible by the definition of $s$ and because $\lambda^\ast\in W$.